# Why does my code loop, when I have no loop command?

Tags: python

I was adding to my Python code, that when you would need to type something, the cursor would show, but after, it would hide. After testing my code, I found that the second part where you must type, it just loops to the start of the question, tells you what you can type for "yes" and "no", and then loops. What happened?

```
import sys, time, os, random  # imports
from getkey import getkey
from replit import audio
from var import *
from loading import *

def underline(yuikjh):
  return "\u0332".join(yuikjh)
  black = "\033[0;30m" 
  red = "\033[0;31m" 
  green = "\033[0;32m" 
  yellow = "\033[0;33m" 
  blue = "\033[0;34m" 
  magenta = "\033[0;35m" 
  cyan = "\033[0;36m" 
  white = "\033[0;37m" 
  grey = "\033[0;90m" 
  gray = "\033[0;90m" 
  bright_red = "\033[0;91m" 
  bright_green = "\033[0;92m" 
  bright_yellow = "\033[0;93m" 
  bright_blue = "\033[0;94m" 
  bright_magenta = "\033[0;95m" 
  bright_cyan = "\033[0;96m" 
  bright_white = "\033[0;97m"
  bold='\033[01m'
  reset='\033[0m'
  


#townboi=audio.play_file("The Never-ending Imaginary Adventures of a Childish Mind.mp3")
#townboi.loops=2 
#townboi.volume=.03
#time.sleep(1)
print1 (blue + '''

===================================================================================================================\n===     =======================================  =========     ===  ===================  =========    =====      ==\n==  ===  ======================================  ========  ===  ==  ===================  ========  ==  ===  ====  =\n=  ================================  ==========  =======  ========  ===================  =======  ====  ==  ====  =\n=  ========  =   ===  =  ===   ===    ===   ===  =======  ========  ===   ===  =  =====  =======  ====  ===  ======\n=  ========    =  ==  =  ==  =  ===  ===  =  ==  =======  ========  ==     ==  =  ===    =======  ====  =====  ====\n=  ========  ========    ===  =====  ======  ==  =======  ========  ==  =  ==  =  ==  =  =======  ====  =======  ==\n=  ========  ==========  ====  ====  ====    ==  =======  ========  ==  =  ==  =  ==  =  =======  ====  ==  ====  =\n==  ===  ==  =======  =  ==  =  ===  ===  =  ==  ========  ===  ==  ==  =  ==  =  ==  =  ========  ==  ===  ====  =\n===     ===  ========   ====   ====   ===    ==  =========     ===  ===   ====    ===    =========    =====      ==\n===================================================================================================================
''')
time.sleep(3)
os.system('clear')
cursor.show()
printt (green + "Please type Username." + bright_blue)
print("")
user = input()
time.sleep(1)
os.system('clear')
cursor.hide()
printt(green + "Logging in, please wait.")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('clear')
#load()
#cursor.show()
os.system('clear')
printt (green + "Welcome " + cyan + user + green +  "!")
time.sleep(0.5)
os.system('clear')
printt(red+"Welcome back Master.\nWhile you were away, many things happened.\n")
printt(green + "Press " + cyan + "ENTER " + green + "to continue.")
getkey()
os.system('clear')
printt(red + "There has been a solar flare that has wiped out 80% of all living things on planet Earth.\nThe date is Thursday, Octember 22, 2374. The time is 16:42 PM\n")
getkey()
os.system('clear')
printt("The world has been sent into utter chaos.\nThe world has been divided into three groups of people.\n1. The Walkers.\n2. The Troopers\n3. The people that decided not to pick sides.")
getkey()
os.system('clear')
printt("We are part of The Walkers, which means we must be very careful not to be found out by The Troopers.")
getkey()
os.system('clear')

active = True
while active:
    printt(red + "Now, We must call the Walkers. Are you ready?\n")
    response = printt(red+"\nyes/no\nType " + cyan + "y, yes " + red + "for yes, and " + cyan + "n, no " + red + "for no.\n")
active = False
cursor.show()
response=input(blue).lower()
os.system('clear')
cursor.hide()
if response in ["yes",'y']:
      printt(red+"Ok, let's get started.\n")
      active = False
elif response in ["no",'n']:
      printt(yellow + "You are not " + blue +  "Master" + yellow + ". Goodbye hacker.") 
quit()
      
printt("Ok, first we must connect to the other Walkers.")
getkey()
os.system('clear')
printt("Please type " + green + "#W4lk3rsJ0in" + red + ".")
response=input(blue).lower()
os.system('clear')
if response in ["#W4lk3rsJ0in"]:
  printt("Connecting...")
elif response in [""]:
  printt(yellow + "Error!1! Error #63\nInvalid input: " + input + ".\nShutting down, good bye!")
quit()
```

Comment: `while active:` is a loop.

Comment: `while` is a loop command. It will continue to run everything inside the `while active` over and over while `active` continues to be true. You need to set `active` to be false sometime inside the loop, so it will exit.

Answer (score 1):

Your while Active loop, doesnt end.
You set active to true and said:
While actrive is true run.
So it runs and runs and runs for inifinte.
You could break the loop with "break" or set active to False in your loop.